# configuring a flatpak app (BlackBox) as the default terminal

Tags: default-programs, flatpak, update-alternatives

So I recently installed the [BlackBox](https://flathub.org/apps/com.raggesilver.BlackBox) terminal. I like it, and would like to set it as the default terminal. However, it's installed through flatpak and when I try running
`sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator` it does not appear as an option:

[image]

I saw that you can register new terminals with the command:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator x-terminal-emulator /path/to/emulator 1
```

But when I looked into what path is used to run Black Box, I found this:

```
/usr/bin/flatpak run --branch=stable --arch=x86_64 --command=blackbox com.raggesilver.BlackBox
```

So how do I configure this as an alternative? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it to work with some dirty hacks, here's how:

1. Create a bootstrap script

   ```bash
   echo > /usr/local/bin/blackbox <<EOF
   #!/usr/bin/env bash
   /usr/bin/flatpak run --branch=stable --arch=x86_64 --command="blackbox" com.raggesilver.BlackBox
   EOF
   sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/blackbox
   ```
2. Install said script as alternative

   ```bash
   sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator x-terminal-emulator /usr/local/bin/blackbox 1
   ```
3. Select it as default:

   ```bash
   sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator
   ```

Comment: That's not really dirty that's a pretty sensible solution! For some reason external software still opens up the default terminal when I try to run it, but this is the correct answer for sure

Comment: This solution worked great. Some apps still default to gnome-terminal based on Default Applications, but this still is mostly what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

Can my example help you? I set up BlackBox launch via standard hotkeys. I went into settings -> search -> key -> custom -> new command `flatpak run com.raggesilver.BlackBox` and set <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> (for Ubuntu)

Comment: That is helpful yes, but I'd like the system to recognize it as I'm often using tools like docker-desktop which has stuff like "launch external terminal" for containers and such. I want to tell the system to use it by default.